# T-SQL - Arithmetic overflow while working with milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very simple script in TSQL that *tries* to convert a timestamp in milliseconds to a `DATETIME` data type. This also includes the local time offset.

```
DECLARE @Time AS BIGINT
SET @Time = 1413381394000 
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
               @Time - DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)) AS [Datetime]
```

The error it's giving me all the time is:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Now, I don't have any *explicit* `int` variables in this query, and any `CAST()` to `BIGINT` or `DECIMAL(13,0)` I've did, resulted in the same error.

Which is the wrong part in this query? Is `int` the default return data type of `DATEDIFF()`?

I know that I could just divide `@Time` by 1000 and work with `SECONDS` instead of `MILLISECONDS`, I just want to know if there is a way to work *directly* with milliseconds, since the idea is to use this script as an Inline Table-Valued Function (cannot use scalar ones for other reasons outside this query).

Comment: That is because the second parameter to DATEADD is an int and you are passing it a value WAY bigger than in int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation for local offset has the potential to be wrong by an hour due to Daylight Savings Time. `DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE())` will only get the current offset and not the offset for the given date. Conversions to and from UTC and local time are generally best handled in application or SQLCLR code due to SQL's lack of functionality for this purpose. See [How can I get the correct offset between UTC and local times for a date that is before or after DST?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28187/50669).

In [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) Microsoft states that:

> number
>       Is an expression that can be resolved to an int that is added
>       to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.
>
> ```
> If you specify a value with a decimal fraction, the fraction is
> truncated and not rounded.
> ```

Therefore, you cannot directly work with millisecond values larger than the maximum value for an int which supports a range of -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) as stated in [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx). You'll have to do to separate date adds and some modulo division.

```
DECLARE @Time bigint
DECLARE @Seconds int
DECLARE @RemainingMilliseconds int
DECLARE @EpochDate datetime

SET @Time = 1413381394000

SET @EpochDate = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
SET @Seconds = @Time / 1000
SET @RemainingMilliseconds = @Time % 1000

SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @RemainingMilliseconds, DATEADD(SECOND,@Seconds, @EpochDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) does indeed return an int, but I suspect that it's [`DateAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) that's giving you the error message.

You'll need to work in that precision, unfortunately, as you said you wanted to avoid, as you're wanting to work in milliseconds.

> DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
>
> `number` Is an expression that can be resolved to an int that is added to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.

You could obviously code your away around it with loops or something, but obviously there's a cost/benefit there that you would need to go through.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to DATEADD should be INT not BIGINT. Convert to seconds and then pass to date add.

```
DECLARE @Time AS BIGINT
SET @Time = 1413381394000 
DECLARE @seconds AS INT = @Time / 1000
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, @seconds, ...)
```

If you don't want to lose milliseconds, you can add a second step:

```
DECLARE @milliseconds INT = @Time % 1000
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @milliseconds, <date from before>)
```